# php data input into MySQL when submitting form

Tags: php, mysql

I've successfully been able to input data into my MySQL database but having trouble inserting the data when submitting the form. At the moment, blank data will insert whenever i load the `register.php` page. I read that I need to possibly put this code in a separate document containing ONLY the php code. I tried that and added that page to the form action. It redirected to the `proccess.php` page but didn't actually insert the data. here is my php:

```
<?php
  $servername = "localhost";
  $username = "root";
  $password = "@Passw0rd";
  $dbname = "accounts";

  // Create connection
  $conn = mysqli_connect($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
  // Check connection
  if (!$conn) {
      die("Connection failed: " . mysqli_connect_error());
  }

  $name = mysqli_real_escape_string($link, $_REQUEST['Ausername']);
  $email = mysqli_real_escape_string($link, $_REQUEST['email']);
  $userPassword = mysqli_real_escape_string($link, $_REQUEST['Apassword']);

  $sql = "INSERT INTO users (username, email, password)
  VALUES ('$name', '$email', '$userPassword')";

  if (mysqli_query($conn, $sql)) {
      echo "New record created successfully";
  } else {
     echo "Error: " . $sql . mysqli_error($conn);
  }

  mysqli_close($conn);
?>
```

and my form:

```
<form class="form-inline" action="register.php" method="post">
    <div class="input-group">
        <span class="input-group-addon"><i class="fa fa-user"></i></span>
        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="Ausername" placeholder="Username" name="Ausername" required>
    </div>
    <br> <br>
    <div class="input-group">
        <span class="input-group-addon"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-envelope"></i></span>
        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="email" placeholder="Email" name="email" required>
    </div>
    <br> <br>
    <div class="input-group">
        <span class="input-group-addon"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-lock"></i></span>
        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="Apassword" placeholder="Password" name="Apassword" required>
    </div>
    <br> <br> <br>
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" id="button" name="submit" value="submit">
        <i class="fa fa-user-plus"></i> Sign Up
    </button>
    <br> <br>
</form>
```

Comment: Side note, don't store plaintext passwords, that is just not a good idea. Use `password_hash()` and `password_verify()` or compatible library. Also, bind parameters, trash the escape string method.

Answer (score 0):

use `$_POST` instead of  `$_REQUEST` and try

```
  $name = mysqli_real_escape_string($link, $_POST['Ausername']);
  $email = mysqli_real_escape_string($link, $_POST['email']);
  $userPassword = mysqli_real_escape_string($link, $_POST['Apassword']);
```

Answer (score 0):

your form action "POST", you should retrieve data using $_POST.

My condition of IF statement , all values are mandatory , you can edit that of your own .

```
 <?php
      $servername = "localhost";
      $username = "root";
      $password = "@Passw0rd";
      $dbname = "accounts";

      // Create connection
      $conn = mysqli_connect($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
      // Check connection
      if (!$conn) {
          die("Connection failed: " . mysqli_connect_error());
      }

    if (isset($_POST["submit"]) && !empty($_POST["Ausername"] && !empty($_POST["email"] && !empty($_POST["Apassword"])) {
      $name = mysqli_real_escape_string($link, $_POST['Ausername']);
      $email = mysqli_real_escape_string($link, $_POST['email']);
      $userPassword = mysqli_real_escape_string($link, $_POST['Apassword']);
      }else {
   // redirect to form page 
      }
      $sql = "INSERT INTO users (username, email, password)
      VALUES ('$name', '$email', '$userPassword')";

      if (mysqli_query($conn, $sql)) {
          echo "New record created successfully";
      } else {
         echo "Error: " . $sql . mysqli_error($conn);
      }

      mysqli_close($conn);
    ?>
```

Comment: oh wow  thank you! I appreciate the help. Only issue I'm having is a missing bracket somewhere possibly. the rest of my code after the closing ?> is still showing as PHP code. I can't seem to target the area.

Comment: :) .... https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work

Answer (score 0):

please first before keeping data from a form in variable first check if post is submitted and chek the codes below

```
<?php
      if(isset($_POST['submit']){
           $name = mysqli_real_escape_string($link, $_POST['Ausername']);
          $email = mysqli_real_escape_string($link, $_POST['email']);
         $userPassword=mysqli_real_escape_string($link,$_POST['Apassword']);
    $query="INSERT INTO users(username, email, password) 
                         VALUES('$name','$email','$userPassword')";
if($query){
   ?>
 <script>
  alert("record added");
  window.location="index.php";//where index.php is a page with your html codes
</script>
}
else
   die(mysqli_error($link));
<?php
 }
?>
```

or you can user `unset($_POST);` after inserting data from data it it help please notify us thanks but rember to use $_POST instead of $_REQUEST